# AngularJS Conditional Partial not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Based on the login status of a user, I'm trying to display different partials.

I'm currently using `Angular-ui-Router` and `TemplateCache`

In the following way

```
ncApp.factory('LoginState', function($http){
    return {
        getLoginState: function(){
            $http.get(serverUrl+"/loginCheck/").
            success(function(data){
                if(data.success == true){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }
    }
})

ncApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('index',{
        url: '/',
        templateProvider: function($templateCache, LoginState){
            template = LoginState.getLoginState() ? 'home.html' : 'index.html';
            return $templateCache.get(template);
        },
        controller: 'indexCtrl'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
})
```

On render, my `Ui-View` in my main `index.html` doesn't render any partial. I've used the directive as follows

```
<section ui-view autoscroll="false" class="ui-view-class">

</section>
```

How do I fix this or better implement conditional partials?

Comment: Is your index.html getting loaded?

Comment: @Thalaivar Yes it is. Browser console shows me an empty `ui-view` section

Comment: template = LoginState.getLoginState() ? 'home.html' : 'index.html'; your condition is right, you are either loading home or index... whats the issue then